# Trying to find second integer in string - Not working

Tags: java, regex, for-loop

I have been trying to find certain integers in a string using regex (I'm not completely sure what it is, could someone refer me something to look at to learn about it?), but have some problems. I've got it working to look for the first integer in a string and set that integer value to a variable, but am stuck when looking for the second. This is my code currently:

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
                    
    current = list[x];
                                                
    Matcher first = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(current);
    first.find();
    min = Integer.valueOf(first.group());
                    
    Matcher second = Pattern.compile("^\\D*\\d+\\D+(\\d+)").matcher(current);
    second.find();
    max = Integer.valueOf(second.group());
                    
    System.out.println("min: " + min + " max: " + max);
                    
                    
}
```

In this case, say the string was "1 guacamole 36", I would want it to set the `min` variable to a value of 1, and the `max` to a variable of 36. How would I do so? All that comes up are errors, I'm assuming from the section with the second matcher.

Please let me know if you can help with either inquiry or if I should add more information - thanks in advance!

P.S. `list` is an array of strings in which I am trying to have, for each string, min and max reset each time to the integers in the strings.

Comment: There is a useful reference for regular expression ("regex") support in the Java API documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `group()` finds group **0** (i.e. the whole match), but the number you want is captured in group **1**, so you should do:

```
max = Integer.valueOf(second.group(1));
```

You don't actually need a second regex to find the second number. Just ask the first matcher to match *again*. It will find the second number:

```
Matcher first = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(current);
first.find();
min = Integer.valueOf(first.group());

first.find(); // call find again!
max = Integer.valueOf(first.group());
```

A safer way to do this is to check if the matcher actually found anything before calling `group`:

```
Matcher first = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(current);
if (first.find()) {
    min = Integer.valueOf(first.group());


    if (first.find()) { // call find again!
        max = Integer.valueOf(first.group());
    } else {
        // can't find a second number!
    }
} else {
    // can't find any numbers!
}
```

Comment: This works splendidly! Thank you so much! Also, is it possible to get the position of the second number found, such as with an index? In the strings I am testing it with, each is set up in this format: "1-36 g: guacamole", so I was wondering if there was a way to find the letter after the two integers, and the full string after the ':' sign. Is that possible, or only numbers?

Comment: @Bubbly it is possible. Regex is a very powerful tool. You can get the index with `start` and `end` methods of the matches. If you want to find other letters, that’s another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a one-liner regex approach, then use `String#replaceAll` with this regex pattern:

```regex
\D*\d+\D+(\d+).*
```

This will capture the second number in the input in the first capture group.  Sample script:

```java
String input = "1 guacamole 36";
String secondNum = input.replaceAll("\\D*\\d+\\D+(\\d+).*", "$1");
System.out.println(secondNum);  // prints 36
```

Note: Should the input *not* have at least two separate numbers in it, then the above replacement would actually just return the input.  In this case, if you wanted to report no match, you should first check for a matching pattern using `String#matches`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep looking next item as long as string contains it and you want to process. As informed in other answers if you are explictly looking for 2nd number then you either use `regex` or use `second.group(1)`.

If you are looking to find the min and maximum number give in a string, here is how i have done:

```java
String text = "1 guacamole 36 admin test 23 which is equivalent 22";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
}
System.out.println(numbers);
Collections.sort(numbers);
int min = -1;
int max = -1;
if (!numbers.isEmpty()) {
    int size = numbers.size();
    min = numbers.get(0);
    max = numbers.get(size - 1);
}
System.out.println("Min : " + min);
System.out.println("Max : " + max);
```

This should print

```
[1, 36, 23, 22]
Min : 1
Max : 36
```